# How to safely Store J.W.T token using java Script or angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jwt, access-token

I found 3 ways to save it on client side (local Storage/session Storage/cookies)..but that's not safe enough.Because client or hacker can modify or replace with another valid re-generated J.W.T-token.
I want to store a token in encrypted way or something that is not possible to hack...
please let me know professional way to work or store  access_token....

Comment: Don't store it on the client, that'll make it secure.

Comment: It's probably the safest to store it in an `HttpOnly`/`Secure` cookie together with a `Secure` cookie for a CSRF token. But you won't be able to access the stored data.

Comment: "Because client or hacker can modify or replace with another valid re-generated J.W.T-token. I want to store a token in encrypted way or something that is not possible to hack" this statement shows that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how JWTs work.  If you're signing them correctly, it's infeasible for a hacker to modify or replace them.  Furthermore, the spec allows for encryption to hide the payload if that's your preference as well.

Answer (score 0):

> "that's not safe enough.Because client or hacker can modify or replace with another valid re-generated J.W.T-token"

So, although I'm unsure of your specific application requirements, I will say this: Storing on the client-side via cookies is the way to go... Cookies are not vulnerable to XSS, and CSRF is an easy fix with modern frameworks. E.g. Only send the JWT cookie via HTTPS and set the `HttpOnly` flag (and perhaps also `Secure` flag). This is a pretty standard practice because it's securer than web storage. **[Check out this article from stormpath](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)**.

Comment: Anyway, @Paul's comment is completely right. No matter where you store the jwt, if someone modifies or replace with another token, the API security mechanisms must be able to detect it.